# Reference an object within a Twitter bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, popover

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to show a popover; so I wrote this:

```
<div class=navbar-right>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href="#" data-container="ul" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"
                data-content="<form class='form-search'>
                <div class='input-group'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='search-text'>
                    <span class='input-group-btn'>
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default' id='search-submit'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i></button>
                         </span>
                </div> </form>" id="home-header-search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Languages </a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

and it works, but now I would like jquery to detect when the button with the if #search-sumbit is clicked. Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
jQuery ->
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({ html : true });
$("#search-submit").click -> 
    console.log("hi")
    return
```

How could I make that button referenceble? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/122534

**Js** :

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({ html : true });
$('[data-toggle=popover]').on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
  $('#search-submit').on('click', function(){
       console.log("hi");
    return false;
  });
});
```

**HTML** :

```
<div class=navbar-right>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href="#" data-container="ul" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"
                data-content="<form class='form-search'>
                <div class='input-group'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='search-text'>
                    <span class='input-group-btn'>
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default' id='search-submit'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i></button>
                         </span>
                </div> </form>" id="home-header-search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Languages </a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I am having some troubles to convert that to coffeescript